# Objective c gps coordinates not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

I have followed many tutorials but none have worked.  The coordinate always outputs 0.000000, 0.000000.

Here is my code for the location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = (CLLocation *)[locations lastObject];

}
-(void)getLocation {
    longitude = floorf(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude * 10000)/10000;

}
```

I have this in a button:

```
locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
[self getLocation];
```

And I have this in the viewDidLoad:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I am using a fake location in the ios simulator in xcode so it should not output 0.000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request authorization to use location services.

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add this line in viewDidLoad:

```
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

If that doesn't work, I'm inclined to say it's because you're running in the simulator.  Even the fake location was screwing me up at one point.  Can you run on a device?

Edit: try adding this to info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application requires location services to work</string>
```

Comment: I can't run on a device at this time.  But I will give this a shot.

Comment: Ya it did not work.  It did not show a authorization pop up.

Answer (score 0):

follow this tutorial you found the lat & long and by using both get the address also...:)

https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/